# ActionBar não mostra o Icon

Tags: android

Estou a usar o *Eclipse "Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)"* para criar os meus projectos em Android.
Sempre que eu crio um projecto qualquer e executo ele, a ActionBar não mostra o icon que está definido no ficheiro **AndroidManifest.xml**: 
`android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

O que tenho de fazer para que o icon da app seja mostrado na `ActionBar`?

Comment: Qual versão do *SDK*? Está usando `AppCompat`? Se possível, mostre seu arquivo de *styles.xml* ou *themes.xml*.

Comment: Olá Paulo Rodrigues! O meu styles.xml é o default: <resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"</style> 
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"> </style>
</resources>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer de duas maneiras:

Pelo arquivo `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="logo">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
</style>
```

Ou diretamente na `Activity`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```